# distributing files to VPN partners

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, vpn, key-exchange

suppose i've created VPN certificates for a certain VPN-RoadWarrior-Client, expressed in the files `VPN-RoadWarrior-Client.key` and `VPN-RoadWarrior-Client.crt`*, however VPN-RoadWarrior-Client is actually in Sweden most of the year, so i need a secure way to deliver these keys to them remotely without compromising the security of the certificate themselves.

So this is a problem of how to bootstrap VPN security with remote clients in a sane way. For example, I could use truecrypt but then i would have to exchange a password through some unsecured channel

Is there some secure way to bootstrap the transfer of the keys?

my preliminar answer is to request the client to run some program that generates public/private key pair, ask him to send me the public key (which would have to be confirmed over phone, which is widely assumed to be a channel that even if non-secure, preserves *integrity* of the messages, which is what would really matter for validating a public key), and i would use the public key to encrypt the files and send them over insecure channels

is there such a program that can encrypt files based on a public key and decrypt from a private one?

- I also need to distribute `CA.crt` but for the purpose of the question, i'm not concerned with the security of distributing this key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your preliminar answer is a good one, if they can install programs use GPGP: http://www.gnupg.org/

Get them to generate a key pair, email you the public key, encrypt whatever you want to that and return over email.

Alternate options are:

- Encrypt with Winzip AES256 option, choosing a long complex password (goodpassword.com) and exchange that out-of-band e.g. phone, sms
- Place the files on an encrypted removable media e.g. hardware encrypted such as Ironkey or encrypted CD / USB and send this via courier / post. Exchange password out-of-band. This is more suitable for larger files than just a certificate and key.

Depending on your risk appetite and the information and systems the VPN provides access to you maybe comfortable also using a "secure" file sharing option e.g. Dropbox or Google apps folder

Comment: i tried GnuPG and it works wonders! thanks for the suggestion.. i wish i could make RSA-4096 though, but i'm happy with 2048

Comment: @lursher glad it worked, whenever you worry about things like RSA 2048 vs 4096 have a look at this: http://xkcd.com/538/